# Lilt vs cadence?

Tags: meaning, difference

I have tried to look for comparison online but it seems that no one else has asked this question - on the internet at least... Comparing the definitions given by the Cambridge Dictionary, it seems that they are completely interchangeable but I would like to ask others about it as well before making such a conclusion.

Definitions:
Cadence: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cadence
Lilt: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lilt

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think of cadence as dealing more with the beat/rhythm and lilt as more with the pitch/tone.

Answer (score 1):

**lilt** is often used about voice, and indicates a **pleasant** rise and fall in pitch, which people feel denotes energy and enthusiasm. I would also associate it with a relatively rapid and rhythmic delivery.

To be honest, I have never heard the term **cadence** used in relation to voice- only music. It comes via the Italian term **cadenza** from the latin root **cadere**, which means fall, and generally describes a downward pitch change indicating the end of a piece of music: it is not ususual for a piece of music  to also slow down as the end approaches. If the same applies to speech, I would not expect it to be used in the same positive way as **lilt**.

The description in the [Oxford dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cadence?q=cadence) indicates that it is a formal term, and quotes this (rather unexciting) example:

> He delivered his words in slow, measured cadences

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cadence) describes it as:

> a falling inflection of the voice

Comment: Exactly! As [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mournful+cadence%2Cmournful+lilt&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmournful%20cadence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmournful%20lilt%3B%2Cc0) shows, it's almost always a ***mournful cadence*** rather than a ***mournful lilt***. But see [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cheerful+cadence%2Ccheerful+lilt&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) - 200 years ago it was nearly always ***a cheerful cadence***, only recently supplanted by ***a cheerful lilt***.